# React Native Flatlist don't rerender on PureComponent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Below is my Flatlist code. It is working fine but it was a bit laggy. So i search a bit on internet and found out that changing Component to PureComponent boost the flatlist performance. So i changed that but after that my iconType dont works. It doesn't changes that checkbox when user touches the list item.  Is PureComponent don't rerender on touch?

```
<FlatList
  style={{flex:1}}
  data={finalData}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  renderItem={({item})=>{
    var iconType = (this.state.selectedItems.indexOf(item.name)>-1?"ios-checkmark-circle":"ios-checkmark-circle-outline");
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={
          ()=>{
            var selectedItems = this.state.selectedItems;
            var selectedItemsData = this.state.selectedItemsData;
            if(selectedItems.indexOf(item.name)>-1){
              const index = selectedItems.indexOf(item.name);
              selectedItems.splice(index, 1);
              selectedItemsData.splice(index,1);
            }else{
              selectedItems.push(item.name);
              selectedItemsData.push({name:item.name,id:item.id});
            }

            this.setState({selectedItems});
            this.setState({selectedItemsData});
          }}>
        <View style={{padding:20,flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'flex-start'}}>
          <Icon name={iconType} color="#45AA6F" size={25} />
          <Text style={{marginLeft:10,paddingTop:4,color:'#9B9B9B',fontWeight:'500'}}>{item.name}</Text>
        </View>
        <Dash style={{height:1}} dashColor="#45AA6F"/>
      </TouchableOpacity>)}
  }
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

PureComponent will prevent wasteful re-renders unless the actual id change,
By passing **extraData={this.state}** to FlatList we make sure FlatList itself will re-render when the state.selected changes. Just add the extraData prop to your flatlist component.  Source: [Official Document Flatlist](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html)

```js
 /* Sample FlatList Example */

import React, { PureComponent} from 'react';
import {
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  Switch,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

export default class FlatListView extends PureComponent {
 
  constructor(props: Object) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      words: [
        { key: 1, text: 'Notification', toggle:false}, 
        { key: 2, text: 'Wifi', toggle:false}, 
        { key: 3, text: 'Bluetooth', toggle:false}
      ]
    }
  };

  render() {
    return( 
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.words}
        extraData={this.state}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => 
          <View style={styles.wordsContainer}>
            <Text>{item.text}</Text>
            <Switch
              style={styles.pilgrimsWordSwitch}
              onValueChange={(toggleValue) => {
             /*
              *  Cloning the words array to temp, So that the reference to this.state.words array will change.
              *  Means this.state.words === temp will give false value.
              */

                let temp = this.state.words.slice(0);
                temp[index].toggle = toggleValue;
                this.setState({words: temp});
              }}
              value={ item.toggle }
            />
          </View>
        }
      />
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wordsContainer: {
    alignItems:'center', 
    backgroundColor:'green',  
    flexDirection:'row',
    height:100, 
    justifyContent:'center', 
    padding:20,
  },
  pilgrimsWordSwitch: {
    flex:1, 
    justifyContent:'flex-end'
  }
});
```

Comment: As you are not updating the data = {finalData} in onpress function. So it will not re-render as the  props{finalData} remain shallow-equal.

Comment: If i change back to PureComponent then it stop changing

Comment: Do have any working example using PureComponent on Touch event

Comment: You are extending with Component. My Script works fine with Component but when I extents it with PureComponent its stops working

Comment: Changed Component to PureComponent

Comment: Once try the updated code If it works then in your make below changes.                { FROM }                                                                                                         var selectedItems = this.state.selectedItems;  
 var selectedItemsData = this.state.selectedItemsData;                                      {  TO  }                                                                                                             var selectedItems = this.state.selectedItems.slice(0);  
var selectedItemsData = this.state.selectedItemsData.slice(0);

Comment: If above one doesn't work try this.                                                                          var selectedItems = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.selectedItems)); 
var selectedItemsData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.selectedItemsData));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176307/discussion-between-mohammed-ashfaq-and-digital-jedi).

Comment: Basically i add all data on componentDidMount and map it over state

Answer (score -1):

dont mutate the array, that can cause component not re-render:

`selectedItems.splice(index, 1);`
replace with non-mutating process.

you can probably use `Array.filter` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
or

`Array.map` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

here you can compare non-mutating vs mutating methods:
https://lorenstewart.me/2017/01/22/javascript-array-methods-mutating-vs-non-mutating/

Comment: I am not following your answer, my issue is totally different. I am not push or slicing anything on touch, i am just changing state of item on touch